# How does the White Balance preview work on the OM-D E-M1?

Tags: white-balance, olympus-omd

I can't figure out how the white balance preview works on the Olympus OM-D E-M1 Mark II, and it is not covered in the official manual.

If you go to the LV control panel, select either of the A/G WB compensation controls, then press OK, it puts you into the WB preview screen, but it is black except for the A/G adjustment bars on the right hand side. At the bottom is a note that says "white balance preview" and then has an icon that looks like the shutter release, but if I depress the shutter release half way, then the adjustment bars disappear and it just goes to the plain LV preview.

I assume that the WB preview is supposed to allow the operator to adjust WB compensation while viewing the effect on the LV screen, but I can't figure out how to get this to work, if indeed that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Were you directed to depress the "shutter release icon" half-way or is this an observation? What happens when you fully release the "shutter release icon" without interruption? Is the "White Balance Preview" procedure covered if not the explanation of the procedure?

Comment: @Stan There is no mention of the feature or the screen in the manual. The WB preview has a message at the bottom that reads "WB Preview -> 0" where 0 has a dot in the center of it and looks like the icon for the shutter release.

Comment: Try the support section of the "ASK OLYMPUS" website for product-specific FAQs and contact information. Especially if it has been neglected in. the manual. http://www.olympusamerica.com/cpg_section/oima_ask_olympus.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
...and it is not covered in the official manual.
```

Well, actually it is (see page 52 of the English manual), and you are well under way. I was intrigued and tried it, and it worked when I used the *viewfinder*. You make the correction you think is going to work, look in the viewfinder and half way press the release button. The viewfinder white balance has changed. It just does not influence LV.

It is also a shortcut. After you have checked the correction, it has applied your changes. If you want to change it more, you have to go back into the menu.

Comment: I could not get it to work. Whether I use the LV or EVF makes no difference, the screen is black when the WB compensation screen is active. Maybe make explicit instructions for the steps you believe to work? Also, what page in the manual are you talking about?

Comment: You are referring to "the screen". Which one is that, there are two screens? How do you use LV? It has no function in this process. The only screen in use is the screen in the EVF. I think you have the steps right but are looking at the wrong "screen".

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I do the procedure while the LV or EVF is active. In both case the screen is black while the compensation bars are active. If you are suggesting a procedure, then you should be more specific about the exact steps in that procedure. Also, you have not said what page on the manual covers this.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the actual answer; but, having written various manuals for equipment there might be some truth in the following as it applies to your treasured possession.

Features implemented and documented do not always match.

- Documented features can be deprecated in the equipment available.
- Documented features can be wrong, erroneous or of low quality.
- Documented features may not have been implemented by the document issue date.
- Features that have not been fully implemented in software are ignored by the documentation.